# C++14 variadic function template expect 2 arguments - 0 provided

Tags: c++

I'm currently working on a variadic function using template, however, I keep getting the same error:

`C2780: 'void print(T,Types...)': expects 2 arguments - 0 provided`

even if it is the simplest one:

```
template <typename T, typename... Types>
void print(T var1, Types... var2)
{
    cout << var1 << endl;

    print(var2...);
}

int main() {
    print(1, 2, 3);
}
```

the same error again. I wonder what's wrong.

Comment: The recursive calls will be `print(1,2,3)` then `print(2,3)` then `print(3)` then `print()` and that last call there is no matching function that takes no arguments

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your calls to `print` will be like this:

```
print(1, 2, 3);
print(2, 3);
print(3);
print();
```

Your template function needs at least one argument (`var1`), and there is no function that takes zero arguments.

This can easily be solved by adding another function overload to handle the "no argument" case:

```
void print()
{
    // Do nothing
}
```

Now this will be called in the

```
print();
```

case, and will end the recursion.

---

If C++17 is possible, then [fold expressions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold) are available and you could do it with only a single function:

```
template <typename... Types>
void print(Types&&... var)
{
    ((std::cout << var << "\n"), ...);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define two separate overloads, with an empty one for the terminating case:

```cpp
void print(){
    cout << endl;
}
```

```cpp
template <typename T, typename... Types>
void print(T value, Types... args){
    cout << value << " ";
    print(args...);
}
```

Comment: While this code may solve the problem the answer would be a lot better with an explanation on how/why it does.  Remember that your answer is not just for the user that asked the question but also for all the other people that find it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).